# Concatenate Different Sized ndarrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Simple data structure question, but I cannot find the correct python syntax to do so. Given numpy arrays (in my actual use, to be read from text files with `np.loadtxt`) such as

```
A=[[1,2],[3,4]]
B=[[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
C=[[11,12],[13,14],[15,10]]
```

i.e., 2D, but all different lengths in one dimension. How can I combine these into a single 3D array, such that `combinedArrays[0]` returns A, or `combinedArrays[:,0]` returns all the first rows, etc?

I have tried `np.append`, `np.stack`, and `np.concatenate`, but none of these have worked. I could expand the smaller matrices with zeros and just top fill, but then that is carrying around a lot of extra zeros for no reason.

Comment: You can't, simply because your arrays have different sizes.

Comment: Can not you just wrap it into an array?

Comment: If you have A LOT of zeros, you can use a sparse matrix. But for the example you've mentioned, you make a fuss out of nothing. In fact, a numpy array with zeros filled in would be more memory efficient that your lists of lists.

Comment: What should `combined[:,2]` do?  Besides indexing what do you plan on doing with the combined array?

Comment: I can't really force them into a single array because the matrices in my actual use case represent different stars, and the various parameters about them (position, velocity, mass, etc) so the matrices I import need to be seperate. `combined[:,2] would give all the 3rd row of each file, and @Reti43 does that argument of "bunch of zeroes" still apply when you have 3000 rows on the smallest and something like 10000 on the largest? Essentially I just want to make a "ragged tensor" of rank 3, but without the math ops on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to use `tensorflow.ragged.constant()`

You can create one using following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
t = [A,B,C]
digits = tf.ragged.constant(t)
```

Then not only you can slice it in the ways you want but also use the other methods present in tensorflow library such as convert it to numpy arrays by using `.numpy()` etc

For more information refer to :[Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor)

Comment: I cannot get this to install. I have tried upgrading to a 64 bit Python 3.9, updated all of my packages, followed all the results I can google, and it just gives me error after error

Comment: Can you please attach the error you are facing in question @BrandonMyers

Comment: Pip was being a pain, somehow unable to find the package to install. I kinda just gave up. From what I can tell, this would do what I want if I could get it installed, but that is a personal issue, not one of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
B=np.array([[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]])
C=np.array([[11,12],[13,14],[15,10]])
```

What about and numpy array of numpy arrays:

```
as_array = np.array([A,B,C])
print(as_array)
[array([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]) array([[ 5,  6],
                        [ 7,  8],
                        [ 9, 10]]) array([[11, 12],
                                          [13, 14],
                                          [15, 10]])]
```

What about a list of arrays:

```
as_list = [A,B,C]
as_list.append(as_list)
print(as_list)
[array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]]), array([[ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10]]), array([[11, 12],
       [13, 14],
       [15, 10]]), [...]]
```

You could also use a dictionary.